# How do I return element inside <tbody> without wrapping its element inside a <div>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
render (){

    var table_labels = this.props.labels.map((label,index)=>{   
        return <th key={index} className="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{label}</th>
    })

    return(
        <table className={`mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp ${s.tableWrapper}`}>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                {table_labels}
            </tr>
            </thead>
             <tbody>
                {this.props.table_data.results.map((row,index)=>
                    <div>
                        <tr key={index}>
                            {this.props.getRow(row)}
                            <td className="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
                                <button onClick={() => this.showEditTable(index)}>Edit</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>   
                        <TypeEditListComponent data={[["1","Fix Dent","Right Front Door"],["2","Fix Dent","Right Front Door"],["3","Fix Dent","Right Front Door"]]}/>
                    </div>  
                )}
             </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```

How do I return element inside "tbody" without wrapping its element inside a "div" as it gives error "div cannot appear as a child of tbody. React does not allow to return elements without wrapping them inside a tag.

Comment: u can write it like this: `<tr key={index}> ......... <TypeEditListComponent .....</tr>` inside map and remove the div.

Comment: I tried that but <TypeEditListComponent> is a table component, so it still gives a error. Basically I am trying to add a sub table inside a table. The sub table will appear just below the row on button click.

Comment: you need another `<tr>` and `<td>` to put it in

Comment: but that does not solves the issue of returning it without wrapping both the <tr> inside a <div> tag

Comment: then use `<tbody>` as wrapping element. A table can have numerous `<tbody>` ... or don't use `<table>`

Comment: I got this error "<tbody> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>"

Comment: no...move outer `<tbody>` to where `<div>` is

Comment: It worked, thank you so much :)